How to prove that the eigenvalues of a positive-definite M-matrix are positive with respect to the positive diagonal congruent transformation matrix?
Let $\mathbf{B}$ be a positive-definite M-matrix. For example
$$\mathbf{B}=
\begin{bmatrix}
2.5 & -0.5 & -1.0
\newline
-0.5 & 3.0 & -1.5
\newline
-1.0 & -1.5 & 4.0
\newline
\end{bmatrix}$$
Let $\mathbf{C}$ be a positive diagonal matrix. For example
$$\mathbf{C}=
\begin{bmatrix}
c_{1} & 0 & 0
\newline
0 & c_{2} & 0
\newline
0 & 0 & c_{3}
\newline
\end{bmatrix}$$
, where $\mathit{c}$$_{1}$, $\mathit{c}$$_{2}$ and $\mathit{c}$$_{3}$ are all positive.
The question is:

Can it be proved that the values of eigenvalues of ($\mathbf{C}$$\mathbf{B}$$\mathbf{C}$) are positively correlated with the diagonal entries of $\mathbf{C}$? In other words, when $\mathit{c}$$_{1}$, $\mathit{c}$$_{2}$ or $\mathit{c}$$_{3}$ increases, the eigenvalues of ($\mathbf{C}$$\mathbf{B}$$\mathbf{C}$) also increase.

A symmetric matrix $A$ is positive definite iff we have $x^TAx > 0$ for all non-zero vectors $x$. Can you use this definition and the fact that $B$ is positive definite to prove that $CBC$ is positive definite?

Of course $\mathbf{C}$$\mathbf{B}$$\mathbf{C}$ is a positive-definite matrix since it is congruent to $\mathbf{B}$. I wonder whether the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{C}$$\mathbf{B}$$\mathbf{C}$ are positive with respect to the diagonal entries of $\mathbf{C}$?

What does “the eigenvalues of $CBC$ are positive with respect to the diagonal entries of $C$” mean?

Sorry for confusion. The question has been re-edited for ease of understanding.

The answer is clearly yes, then, because $CBC$ has the same eigenvalues as $B^{1/2}C^2B^{1/2}$. When $C$ increases, $C^2$ also increases (because it is a diagonal matrix). Therefore $B^{1/2}C^2B^{1/2}$ also increases in positive semidefinite partial ordering.
